# System API Usage does not coincide with numbers shown in "API Calls Made Within Last 7 Days"

Tags: api

Has anyone else noticed that their System API Usage numbers are drastically different than the numbers shown when running the Admin report "API Calls Made Within Last 7 Days"?

The report is showing somewhere around 150k API calls in the last 2 days but our API Usage dashboard is showing around 3x that number.

Answer (score 4):

The report shows calls made from midnight to midnight, while the last 24 hour usage is a rolling 24 hour window. Also, the last 24 hour usage stat only counts "metered" requests. Some API calls are "unmetered," such as the `getServerTimeStamp()` call, but should still appear in the API Usage Per User report. The first fact is particularly important, because it means that reporting on the "last two days" is reporting at least 24 hours and up to 48 hours worth of usage, while the 24 hour stat is strictly less than 25 hours.

Finally, it's worth noting that the 24 hour window on the API Usage report is most likely based on GMT, although I can't find any documentation that proves or disproves this final statement. The net result is that it wouldn't be unusual for the API usage report to show at least twice what the 24 hour rolling window report shows when using "last 2 days", while the 24 hour rolling window should always show a higher number than a report with "api calls made today."

Use the API Usage Report to determine general API usage over time (how are your users utilizing the platform) and see trends (which integrations/users are over-utilizing the platform consistently), and use the 24 hour rolling window to see how many more API calls you have before your organization is locked out for over-utilization.

Comment: Thanks. The funny thing my 24 hour usage 1 day last week was higher than what the "7 days API usage" report shows when I ran the report 2 days later.

I have a ticket open with Salesforce trying to explain how this could be possible.

Comment: It's the midnight to midnight deal going on. Say there's 1000 calls at 6pm, and 500 calls at 6am. The 7 days reports two days later would show 1000 on one day, and 500 on another day, but the cumulative total when you checked at 6am would be 1500. That's how it happens.

Comment: I understand that. Your example shows that the numbers add up. 1500=1500. 
I'm saying on Wednesday the 24 hour usage report shows I hit my limit of say 100 API calls. 
On Friday when I run the 7 day usage report it shows. Sun=10, Mon=10, Tues=10, Wed=20, Thurs=10, Fri=10, Sat=10
So in 24 hours they say I had 100 calls but for an entire 7 days I supposedly only had 80. The numbers don't add up. I'm obviously just making those numbers up but this is essentially the problem I encountered.

Comment: Are you using the default built-in report or a customized one? You could be filtering out some of the API calls, for example. In my experience, though, the 24 hour rolling window is always accurate within a few minutes of actual usage, while the report is usually accurate only to the day, and it's often hard to get the numbers to add up exactly. I've never heard of a discrepancy this large though, which makes me think the report was filtered somehow.

Comment: It was the built-in report. No customizations.  Yeah this has me stumped as well. It's been escalated within Salesforce to try to determine how this happened.